# How does the minus come in Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I'm looking into the geometric series and can't understand how the 1 - .01 comes in below:

```
0.272727... = 0.27 + 0.0027 + 0.000027 + 0.00000027 + ...
             = 0.27 + 0.27(.01) + 0.27(.01)^2 + 0.27(.01)^3 + ...
             = 0.27 / (1-.01)
             = 0.27 / 0.99
             = 27/99
             = 3/11
```

Comment: First term over (1 - ratio) for sum, when ratio is between -1 and 1.

Comment: For a finaite geometric progression $\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}.$ See here for the derivation. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Comment: They're skipping steps.  The sum of an geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r^i=\frac{1}{1-r}$ when $|r|<1$.  So, in this case, you have $r=0.01$.

Answer (score 1):

By induction it's easy to prove that

$$\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;:\;\;(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

From here we get the formula for the sum of a *finite* geometric progression:

$$\sum_{k=0}^naq^k=a(1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^n)=a\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

Now, we have that $\;|q|<1\implies q^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , so now put all together and get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from a general formula for how you evaluate a geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ax^n = \frac{a}{1-x},$$

which holds when $|x|<1$.

For a proof of this, you might want to check out this wiki-article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

This shows you how the "$-1$" pops up for a geometric terms with a finite number of terms, and it will be similar (by going to the limit) for an infinite number of terms. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Question is why do solve it using geometric progressions at all. When you use the basic method taught as kids in school, you're basically deriving the sum of an infinite GP unknowingly. Here's the easiest way-

x=0.272727272727...
And 100x=27.272727272727....
Thus, 99x=27
x=27/99

This is basically like deriving the sum of an infinite gp, only instead of a and r, we're using numbers here!